# Optional upload field javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to make an optional upload field by adding the attribute disabled on an upload field whenever the radio button with the value false is checked. and if the user clicks on the other radio button the attr disabled need to be removed again.

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rLep4pd/)

and here is my script that does the adding and removing. note that im not great at these languages.

```
$(function(){
    if($("#optionsRadios1").is(":checked")){
        $("#optupload").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else if($("#optionsRadios2").is(":checked")){
        $("#optupload").attr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Hope you guys can help me out

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Try - http://jsfiddle.net/8rLep4pd/4/  - added class to your radios' and added a little js - should suit your need.

Comment: If you can you should add it as answer so i can vote it up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler listening the change and **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** for updating the `disabled` property

```
 $('[name="radioupload"]').change(function () {
     $("#optupload").prop("disabled", this.value != 'yes');    
 });
```